# How to update a GUI using MVC pattern in java

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

Using MVC Pattern in java: 
I have 5 classes (View (GUI), Controller, Model, Class1 & Class2). When i click on a start button, the controller starts a thread in the Model which in turn starts 2 other threads T1 (implemented in Class 1) & T2(implemented in class2).

T1 should display some information onto a `JTextArea`-1 and then after 5 seconds T2 should remove the data from `JTextArea`-1 and paste it to `JTextArea`-2.

i have got T1 working. it displays the information onto the `JTextArea`-1. But my concern is regarding the starting of the next tread and its implementation.

How can T2 talk to the same Model and get the same update method of the View to be invoked but with different set of actions to be performed?

Thread T1 in class1:

```
public void run() {

    while(!R.isFinished()) {

    System.out.println("inside kitchen thread");
    String report="";int size =0;
    String str="";int tn=0;

    report = getOrderReport();
    size= report.length();

    for(int i=1;i<=size;i=i+43){
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        str = report.substring(i,i+43);
        tn=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(8,9));
        System.out.println("inside kitchen thread order seq num: " +OrderSeq.getInstance().getNext());
        OrderSeq.getInstance().setLog(str);
        R.receiveAnOrder(str,tn);
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Kitchen thread exception" + e.getStackTrace());
    }


}
```

In the above code: R.receiveAnOrder(str,tn) communicates with the model to update the view.

How can i call the same or maybe another function in the Model to update the view with details from another thread?

Comment: Description in words is nice, code (what you have done so far) is much better.

Comment: Yeah code or some type of UML diagram would really help here...

Comment: Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html before using extra threads with Swing application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a couple of model classes

You'll need an Order

```
public Order {

  private String name;

  public Order(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

And a list of orders

```
public OrderList extends DefaultListModel<Order> {

}
```

And a cook to cook the orders

```
public void Cook extends Thread implements ActionListener {

  private OrderList waiting;

  private OrderList finished;

  private boolean keepCooking;

  public Cook(OrderList waiting, OrderList finished) {
    this.waiting = waiting;
    this.finished = finished;
    this.keepCooking = false;
  }

  public void run() {
    keepCooking = true;
    while (keepCooking) {
      if (orders.size() > 0) {
        try {
          currentOrder = orders.remove(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // someone else emptied the list
        }
      }
      prepareOrder(order);
      if (keepCooking && orders.size() <= 0) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // back to work
        }
      }
    }
 }

 public void prepareOrder(Order order) {
   try {
      Thread.sleep(Math.random() % 10000);
      finished.add(order);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      waiting.add(order);
    }
  }

  public void goHome() {
    keepCooking = false;
  }
}
```

and you'll need some customers to place the orders

```
public Customers extends Thread {

  private OrderList orders;

  public Customers(OrderList orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
  }

  public void run() {
    int number = 0;
    while (true) {
      number++;
      try {
        Thread.sleep(Math.random() % 10000)
        orders.add(new Order(String.format("Order %d", number)));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now a component to help configure the Controller

```
public CloseKitchen extends AbstractAction {

  private Cook cook;

  public CloseKitchen(Cook cook) {
    super("Close Kitchen");
    this.cook = cook;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    cook.goHome();
  }
}
```

... in some block of code ...

```
// building the model
OrderList waiting = new OrderList();
OrderList finished = new OrderList();
Cook cook = new Cook(waiting, finished);
Customers customers = new Customers(waiting);

// attaching the view
somePanel.add(new JList(waiting));
somePanel.add(new JList(finished));

// building the controller plug-in
CloseKitchen closeKitchen = new CloseKitchen(cook);

// wiring the plugin into the controller
somePanel.add(new JButton(closeKitchen));

// show the view
somePanel.setVisible(true);

// start the cook and customers
cook.start();
customers.start();
```

and you will see the orders populate in one list and move to the other.  That is, until you click the "Close Kitchen" button, after which the cook will `goHome()` and the Customers will keep ordering.

There are many ways to implement the Cook and Customers.  I deliberately didn't use a ListDataListener implementation to avoid confusion about what the model needed to use.  Basically, the real model doesn't have to use anything swing related for its internal coordination, provided it can be adapted to the correct `[List|Table|Button|...]Model` interface.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you have trouble understanding MVC, start by looking at the Listener pattern more closely.  MVC is a pattern that is built by combining listeners, and carefully assigning responsibilities to classes.  The key is that an object being listened to doesn't depend on much in the Listener, so a model doesn't depend much on the View.  You can even have 3 views on the same model (perhaps each shows part of the data, or shows it differentl).  The Controller then manipulates Views and Models as a response to input.

Answer (score 1):

You can let the `Views` observe the `Model`. That means each time your thread changes the `Models` data, all registered views update.

```
T1     ---  uses `Controller` to manipulate `Model` (e.g. `Model`.value1) -->  `Controller`
T2    ---   uses `Controller` to manipulate `Model` (e.g. `Model`.value1) -->  `Controller`
`View1`  --- observes `Model`, shows Model.value1 on update --> `Model`
`View2`  --- observes `Model`, shows Model.value2 on update --> `Model`
```

So following your explanation T2 would let the `Controller` read `Model`.value1, clear it and set the value to `Model`.value2. When the Controller changes the `Models` values, it says instructs the registered `Views` to update (2 Views in your case). So then `View1` clear its `JTextField` because `Model`.value1 is empty and `View2` updates its `JTextField` to `Model`.value2.

To implement the update mechanism of the View, read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) tutorial for the observer pattern.

Further more, keep in mind that GUI operations (e.g. with `SWING`) from a thread have to be done by the EventDispatcherThread (EDT). `SwingUtilities` offer an function for this. Simply run all GUI related code from other threads like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       //Do the gui stuff here
    }
});
```

Read more about the EDT and SwingUtitlities [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml).